# King Yoash murdered - Who's responsible?

Tags: history, murder, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of

[II Melechim 12:21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b12.htm#21) and [II Divri HaYamim 24:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b24.htm#25) both indicate that servants conspired and killed King Joash. There seems to be a little bit of confusion on the murderers' names---Yozacar vs Zabad ben Shimeath(an Ammonite in II Div. HaYamin) and Yehozabad ben Shomer/Shimrit(a Moabite in II Div. Hayamin). Whatever their names and nationalities were, [II Melechim 14:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b14.htm#5) and [D. HaYamim 25:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b25.htm#3) both indicate that Amaziah followed Torah law by executing his father's murderers and not their sons.

On the other hand, Pritchard's ANET has an inscription from the ruling Assyrian king, Adad-Nirari III, which states that, in 804/803 BCE, he laid siege to Jerusalem, took the city on 2 Adar, and appointed a new king of his liking(16-year old Amazyahu).  Is there any information anywhere in the extant literature that clears up this situation??

Comment: Thanks, Double AA--my curiosity on this one has been bothering me since I read the Pritchard--there seems to be a LOT more ancient politics in ancient Israel and Judah than the Tanach indicates...my extremely wise British Museum tourguide pal didn't know this one, while he was showing us the Lachish reliefs and Tirhakah's statues...Thanks for enabling me to offer bounties with one point to spare!

Comment: That shouldn't be too surprising. All the other people in the world had lives too :) The Tanach is a view into a very narrow part of history.

Comment: That's what the Pritchard is good for...I still feel like a kid @ 47 compared to you Talmudic scholars on this board...all I have working knowledge of so far is Tanach, Josephus, Dead Sea Scrolls, Roman & early Church history, Pritchard, Bib Arch Review, and my own synthesis & curiosity...the history is fascinating but there's SO many holes...wish we had the Visions of Gad, Shemyahu, and Iddo, and the REAL Chronicles of the Kings to peruse and fill in some details....